# How to move WPF window above top of screen?

Tags: wpf

I have a window with the following:

```
Background="{x:Null}" AllowsTransparency="True" WindowStyle="None"
```

Dragging the window by hand beyond the left, right and bottom limits of the screen results in a predictably cropped window. However this behaviour is not the same for dragging it above the top limit. Instead of cropping, it pushes it back down as if there's an automatic `If Window.Top < 0 Then Window.Top = 0`.

This is probably in place so that users don't lose a Windows titlebar (which is the standard way to drag windows around, and losing sight of that effectively makes it undraggable). I don't need that as my entire window is draggable via `Me.DragMove()`.

So, **how do I let a window be dragged above the top limit of the screen**?

(This is unrelated to Aero Snap which only occurs if the mouse touches the borders. I'm trying to move the window beyond visible bounds)

Comment: What is that you're doing to set Top? Just setting a negative Top value on a Window works just fine.

Comment: @John Bowen: Manually dragging by hand

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The DragMove function do not allow you to drag a window above the screen. You need to manually move the window, for example:

[How do I move a wpf window into a negitive top value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/328127/how-do-i-move-a-wpf-window-into-a-negitive-)

Comment: ah snap, i never saw that. exactly what i was after!