# Using DragMove on a WPF window will not allow me to move the window to a negative Top value

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF window and I'm using DragMove to drag the window around.  When I drag it off the top of the screen it snaps back to a 0 top value.  Is there a way to disable this programatically?

Comment: I think that's Windows behavior, not WPF's.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/331251/718325) seems to provide something that works.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/331251/718325